# Trying to Login through AJAX Asp.net - MVC 3 - Not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

i've been trying to login through AJAX but somehow its not working.

my controller action is

```
       public string CheckLogin(Users checkuser)
       {
            if (db.CheckUserLoginDetails(checkuser.Email, checkuser.Password))
            {
                return "Login Successful:" + checkuser.Email;
            }
            else
            {
                return "Login UnSuccessful";
            }
        }
```

my View AJAX code is

```
        $(':submit').click(function (e) {
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        var postdata =
        {
            'Email': username,
            'Password': password
        };
        $.post({
            url: 'http://localhost:7651/Home/CheckLogin',
            data: postdata,
            success: function (msg) {
                $('#Result').html(msg);
            }
        });
    });
```

i don't know whats wrong in the code ..but some how its not making a call to controller action at all...

1. yes i am runing on localhost
2. CheckLogin action is i Home Controller
3. Routes are defualt...
4. will try to have a look on net panel.. dont have any idea on that
5. USERs Model

   ```
       [Key]
       public virtual int UserID { get; set; }

       [Required(ErrorMessage="Required")]
       public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }

       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
       public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
       [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
       public virtual string Email { get; set; }

       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
       [DataType(DataType.Password)]
       public virtual string Password { get; set; }

       [DataType(DataType.Date)]
       public virtual DateTime JoiningDate { get; set; }
   ```
6. i have tried the breakpoints but the calls are not going and breakpoints are never hitting...
7. Result DIV exits in DOM .. in index view/ in HTML.BeginForm()
8. dont know how to add error to $.AJAX

Thanks for all the checklist though.... please help

here is the view ...

```
@model Temp1.Models.Users

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js") type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js") type="text/javascript"></script>


<h2>Login</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("CheckLogin", "Home"))
{ 
    @*<p>
        <input type="text" id="username" value="" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="password" id="password" value="" />
    </p>
    *@

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)

    <p>
        <input type="button" value="Login" id="btnLogin" />
    </p>


    <div id="Result">

    </div>


}


<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#btnLogin').click(function (e) {
        var postdata =
        {
            "Email": "temp@temp.com",
            "Password": "temp123"
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("CheckLogin","Home")',
            data: postdata,
            success: function (msg) {
                $('#Result').html(msg);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                $('#Result').html(msg);
            }

        });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax submit url should be like this '/controler/action'. The best practice is to use `Url.Action("actionName","ControlerName")` if not you will have to change your jQuery when you deploy somewhere else.

```
 $.post({
        url: '@Url.Action("CheckLogin","Home")'
        data: postdata,
        success: function (msg) {
            $('#Result').html(msg);
        }
    });
```

if doing this only not  working, try changing your action like this,

```
 public string CheckLogin( string Email, string Password){

}
```

and change your postData,

```
 var postdata =
    {
        Email: username,
        Password: password
    };
```

Comment: Oh try changing  your postData like above.

Comment: no luck ... :( do you think i need to prevent the submit button to post the form ... like e.preventDefault()

Comment: ah don't use a submit button. Because you don't need to submit (You are using ajax post). Just you a HTML button with some Id and change your Jquery Selector

Comment: can you see a post in firebug

Comment: No POST Request ... only GET i can see in firebug

Comment: i have edited the post and posted my View code... please have a look

Comment: Ok ... i dont know what i did but now its working perfectly fine with the dummy data ...could you pleae tell me how can i retrive the value from @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.email) in Jquery..please

Comment: wrap your javascript function with `$(document).ready(function(){ // your code here ..})`

Comment: Whoopy...... its working perfectly fine now.... even with the actual data .... all i had to do is check the source of the page.. i found that @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.email) generates the id for text box which you can retrive through JQUERY....thnk you all of you guys ...

Answer (score 0):

Your post leaves me with more questions than answers.  I would spend some time debugging ...

1. Is your website running on port 7651?
2. is CheckLogin in your Home controller?
3. Are your routes the default routes, or what's your mapping like?
4. if you use net panel in FireBug do you see a request go out?  What's the result of call?
5. Whats the "Users"  model look like (could be a binding error)?
6. Have you put a breakpoint in an OnException method in your controller ?
7. Does #Result exist in your DOM (try an alert in the successfunction)?
8. have you tried adding the "error" property to your ajax call and interrogating the issue?

Comment: Should i have to use AJAX.Beginform() instade of html.BeginForm() ?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller action is returning a string not an ActionResult which in this case would be a ContentResult.

Try:

```
public ContentResult CheckLogin(Users checkuser)
   {
        if (db.CheckUserLoginDetails(checkuser.Email, checkuser.Password))
        {
            return Content("Login Successful:" + checkuser.Email);
        }
        else
        {
            return Content("Login UnSuccessful");
        }
    }
```

Comment: either way you need this though : )   Load up fiddler and ensure the request is even coming across. Next you may want to use GLIMPSE route debugger.

Comment: Ok ... i dont know what i did but now its working perfectly fine with the dummy data ...could you pleae tell me how can i retrive the value from @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.email) in Jquery

Comment: Go back to using a string instead of content result. Recompile and run again. If it breaks.... Mark this as the answer :)